# How to set Camera View a Specific Area in UI

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, camera, unity-ui

My all project works in UI. One of my scene has videoPlayer and I would like to set my MainCamera to that specific Area. This scene is my Recording scene but for recording I have to use canvas Render Mode and has to be "Screen Space - Camera". How I can set my camera view to that specific area.
I tried 2nd camera with culling mask but didn't work because videoplayer is already my UI's child when camera Renders UI showing all children objects.

Is it possible show to camera whereever I want in UI?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REKbA.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Yessir it sure is. I literally had to do this a couple of days ago. Here is a [tutorial/video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DjR2O8EKPA&list=PLT-js14uRi2r4ApmP0zmhMy8OKbosObTf&index=13&t=131s) I followed to figure out how to do it for my application. From the sounds of it, all you need to do is follow the video up to ~3 minutes. Then utilize the end product of getting a camera to showcase something in a UI window for your application.

For reference if the video gets deleted the process is as follows:

1. Create a new GameObject within the `Canvas`
2. Add a `Raw Image` as a child to to the new GameObject

We want a raw image because Raw Images in particular support the addition of a 2d Texture and this is what we need in order to display the Camera view.

3. Add a new `Camera` as a child to the GameObject
4. Create a new `Render Texture` in you Project Folder
5. Add the `Render Texture` to your Camera's `Camera` Component in the `Target Texture` field
6. Add the `Render Texture` to you Images `Raw Image` Component in the `Texture` field
7. Move the `Camera` to what you want to view and it should project to your UI GameObject.
8. If it doesn't do this correctly or the image has weird aspect ratios, check the dimensions in the `Render Texture` and your `Image`. It took me a while to get everything to look normal but it really just takes dimension adjustments.

Hope this helps!

Comment: First of all thanks for awsome and fast reply. I did all steps but in the 7th step wherever I drag to camera doesn't show anything. I can see only blue blank preview and also in the codemonkey he has game scene to show but in my project I have only UI menu (just one canvas and rawImage for videoPlayer)

Comment: Gotcha. I missed a piece of your question. Take the 'Render Texture' and add it to the 'Target Texture' on the Video Player. I'm a bit confused as to why you need a camera in this case. What is the camera supposed to show to the player if the Video Player is already in the UI?

Comment: I'm using NatCorder (https://docs.natsuite.io/natcorder/) plugin for trying to capture what camera sees. My main camera has application panel, buttons etc. and all things stays in the UI like I mentioned before in UI culling mask couldn't work , that's why I'm trying to capture certain area with 2nd cam.